# Enable debug logging in vhost Apache 2.4.6

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

I have an apache server (I didn't do the setup). The `httpd.conf` is default and I see nothing about logging.

in `conf.d/vhost_xxx` I see some config for my vhost.
I add the `LogLevel debug`:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>

        ServerName xx
        ServerAdmin xx
        DocumentRoot "/srv/www/html/"


        LogLevel debug
        ErrorLog logs/xx
        CustomLog logs/xx


</VirtualHost>
```

I reload (also restarted) my apache:

```
service httpd restart
```

But my logs aren't in debug mode. It's just the basic logging.
What am I missing here?